# How to merge two images into a single image in iPhone Apps?

Tags: iphone

In my apps i designed a frame for camera viewer when i click the capture button i should get a single image along with my frame merged over the captured image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to achieve something like this was basically take a programatic screenshot of the area. You could maybe take the picture first and then apply the frame over it and then use the following code to take a screenshot. Make sure both the image and the frame are subViews of a UIView. In the example both of them would need to be part of "saveView".

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(saveView.bounds.size);
[saveView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: hi., i fixed the frame in the camera viewer. the user has to adjust their capture view to fit the image according to frame aft tat only i need to merge two images.i want a single image how the user captures with the frame.

Comment: The above code should still work, but instead of saveView.bounds.size use your UIImagePickerView's bound.size and add the frame as a subview of it.